# Trouble getting opacity to animate to specific value

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, opacity

I'm trying to use the [Humanized Messages](http://code.google.com/p/humanmsg/) jQuery plugin and I'm having some trouble with it. The message would not fade out at all even though I would move the mouse/the final timeout would fire. I thought it was something to do with the coding style/the latest version of jQuery. I rewrote the plugin to my own coding style and checked the jQuery documentation - everything is up to snuff.

The problem, I found out, it that this code (where `humanMsg.msgOpacity` is `0.8`) is animating the opacity to "0.800000011920929" instead of simply "0.8":

```
jQuery('#'+humanMsg.msgID).show().animate({ opacity: humanMsg.msgOpacity}, 200, function(){
    jQuery('#'+humanMsg.logID).show().children('ul').prepend('<li>'+msg+'</li>').children('li:first').slideDown(200);

    if (jQuery('#'+humanMsg.logID+' ul').css('display') == 'none')
    {
        jQuery('#'+humanMsg.logID+' p').animate({ bottom: 40 }, 200, 'linear', function(){
            jQuery(this).animate({ bottom: 0 }, 300, 'easeOutBounce', function() { jQuery(this).css({ bottom: 0 }) });
        });
    }
});
```

Why is this happening and how can I prevent it? I'm running Chrome 13.0.782.220.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decided to cheat with this one:

```
if (jQuery('#'+humanMsg.msgID).css('opacity') >= (humanMsg.msgOpacity - 0.05))
{
    jQuery('#'+humanMsg.msgID).animate({ opacity: 0 }, 500, function() { jQuery(this).hide() });
}
```